# How to affirm equivalent event?

Tags: probability

From the textbook

> "**Probability, Statistics and Random Processes for Electrical Engineering** "3rd edition p. 154

---

> A binary transmission system sends a '$0$' bit by transmitting a $-v$ voltage signal, and a '$1$' bit by transmitting a $+v$. The received signal is corrupted by Gaussian noise given by 
>   $$Y=X+N$$
>   where $X$ is the transmitted signal, and $N$ is a noise voltage with pdf $f_N(x)$. Assume $P[\text '1\text ']=p=1-P[\text '0\text ']$.

My question is:

The textbook says the event $\{Y<x\mid X=v\}$ is equivalent to $\{v+N<x\}$.

However I think $$\{Y<x\mid X=v\} \equiv \{X+N<x\mid X=v\} \equiv \{v+N<x\mid X=v\}$$

How to obtain the correct result?
Are $\{v+N<x\}$ and $\{X=v\}$ independent?

I do always have trouble in judging the equivalent event.

Comment: Maybe the book means to say $\{Y < x,\, X = v\} \equiv \{X + N <x,\, X = v\} \equiv \{v + N < x\}$.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume $N,X$ are independent. So that means $\{v+N\lt x\mid X=v\} = \{v+N\lt x\}$.